# What is the American word for 'tea-towel'?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

On a tour from Australia to the states my wife asked me to stop at the gift store and buy memorable fridge-magnets and [tea-towels](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tea_towel). Everywhere I went, none of the store attendants seemed to know what the latter was. My question is: What is the American word for 'tea-towel'?

Comment: This is the kind of question that needs images. For the US readers, these are (fancy) tea towels a la British http://www.johnlewis.com/home-garden/kitchen/kitchen-linens/tea-towels/c8000031178/pg-view-all and this is a commemorative tea towel http://www.jarrold.co.uk/UserData/root/Images/Basement/milly%20green/Royal-Baby-Tea-Towel-MG.jpg .  It's quite plausible that Americans just don't have them. Maybe more Americans have dish washerS?

Comment: @Lembik Why not edit them in, then? :)

Comment: Tea towels are a very commemorative thing; I'm not sure why. I think every British child (or person who has ever been a child in Britain) has, at some point, had a tea towel made in school where everyone draws a picture of their own face or somesuch, and then the parents pay to get one. Odd really isn't it to use a depiction of your own child's face to mop up spillages and remove excess moisture from pans.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18974/discussion-on-question-by-hawkeye-what-is-the-american-word-for-tea-towel).

Comment: Comments averring "Never heard of this" are not helpful in determining the answer to the question.

Comment: @Lembik: How is it that you imply tea towels and dish washers are mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I guess they are called:

[Dish towels](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dish+towel):

> - a rectangular piece of absorbent cloth (or paper) for drying or wiping
>
>   - **A tea towel or drying-up cloth (English), or dish towel (American)** is a cloth which is used to dry dishes, cutlery, etc., after they have been washed.
>   - In 18th century England, a tea towel was a special linen drying cloth used by the mistress of the house to dry her precious and expensive china tea things. Servants were considered too ham-fisted to be trusted with such a delicate job, although housemaids were charged with hand-hemming the woven linen when their main duties were completed.Tea towels have been mass-produced since the Industrial Revolution.

[Ngram - BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drying-up%20cloth%2C%20%20dish%20cloth%2Cdishcloth%2Cdish%20towel%2Cdishtowel%2Ctea%20towel%2Ctea-towel%2Cteatowel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrying%20-%20up%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishcloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishtowel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20-%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteatowel%3B%2Cc0):   dish towel/tea towel/drying-up cloth/dishcloth.

[Ngram - AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drying-up%20cloth%2Cdish%20cloth%2Cdishcloth%2Cdish%20towel%2Cdishtowel%2Ctea%20towel%2Ctea-towel%2Cteatowel&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrying%20-%20up%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishcloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishtowel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20-%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteatowel%3B%2Cc0):  dish towel/tea towel/drying-up cloth/dishcloth

(from [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towel)): *Towel*.

Comment: I'm a Brit and I'm sure I've never heard anyone say *drying-up cloth*.

Comment: *Dishcloth* is another common alternative, though *dish towel* is probably more dominant (based on my own experience in the US together with this interesting ngrams graph: http://goo.gl/sxyPFK )  @chiastic-security: as a fellow Brit, *drying-up cloth* was the name my family used when I was growing up (in London, one parent from Essex, one from Australia).

Comment: @PLL _Dishcloth_ is the only term that makes any kind of sense to me. This is certainly due to parallel-language interference on my part (and a bit ranty to boot), but _tea-towel_ and _dish-towel_ have always seemed to me quite ludicrously absurd names to give this poor object. It’s **not** a towel, after all: it’s a much thinner piece of cloth, and it’s not terrycloth. Same thing with paper ‘towels’ (= kitchen rolls)—they’re not even cloth! This monstrous misnomering in the English tongue has always made me shake my head rather more contumeliously than is good for my health.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet- How do you define *towel*?  To me it's a piece of cloth (or more generally material) that's absorbent used to dry things. In this case dishes.

Comment: To me, *dishcloth* means the cloth used for *washing* the dishes. (I'm an American raised partly in Australia, FWIW.)

Comment: *Il ne faut pas mélanger les torchons et les serviettes.*

Comment: @Jim That’s where the parallel-language interference comes in, I fear. When I hear _towel_, I immediately and invariably think of thick terrycloth. In Danish, which is the language of my environment, there is no word that really corresponds precisely to _towel_; the usual equivalent, _håndklæde_, is only the kind of towel you dry off with after a shower or take to the beach, made of terrycloth. The others are _klude_ (cloths) or _papir_ (paper), and the thing you use for _washing_ the dishes is a brush. Dischloths/tea-towels are _viskestykker_, which is literally … ‘rubbing/wiping pieces’ (!).

Comment: (Unlike in the UK and Ireland—and possibly America as well, I don’t know—our _viskestykker_ are always made of much thinner cotton, never terrycloth. That just adds to the unwillingness in my brain of accepting paper towels and tea-towels as ‘proper’ towels. Of course, _drying-up cloth_ makes perfect sense to me as well, but like chiastic-security, I’ve never heard that term used either.)

Comment: @ LarsH Same thing in western Canada.  Dishcloth is roughly the size as a facecloth, but used for washing dishes, while dishtowel, is tea towel equivalent.

Comment: @Drew: is that an actual quote from somewhere..? (Which, oddly enough, Google Translate translates as "Do not mix apples and oranges", but even me with my 40+-year-old schoolboy French knew that "serviette" had nothing to do with fruit :-)

Comment: I believe Lynn's answer is the more appropriate one. The OP is asking for the towel you commonly hang at the door of your oven and likely don't use for anything but kitchen decoration. Dish-towel may be a very similar thing, but there's a clear distinction in my house between the wedding/Christmas/Thanksgiving tea-towels (or kitchen-towels) that go on the oven handle, and the towels we use to clean things up.

Comment: This is the Ngram with the [AMERICAN corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drying+up+cloth%2Cdish+cloth%2Cdishcloth%2Cdish+towel%2Cdishtowel%2Ctea+towel%2Cteatowel&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdish%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishcloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishtowel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteatowel%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This is the Ngram with the [BRITISH corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drying+up+cloth%2Cdish+cloth%2Cdishcloth%2Cdish+towel%2Cdishtowel%2Ctea+towel%2Cteatowel&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdish%20cloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishcloth%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdish%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdishtowel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctea%20towel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteatowel%3B%2Cc0) Quite different results.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - they show that 'dish towel' is the term used in US.

Comment: Your link showed the BrEng results. For what that's worth. And can you guarantee me that the expression *dishcloth* is not *also* used for washing the plates? Ngrams, beware of them, you need to know their limits.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Seems we Dutchies do it the same way as in Denmark. Handdoek or droogdoek (doek==klaede) made from terrycloth to dry hands/body, etc. Theedoek made from linnen for dishes, ceramics, porcelain. Glazendoek is a special cotton/linnen mixture variant (less hard fibers) to dry glass-work and fine china without scratching.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I think I am aware of the limits, but I don't understand your issue with dishcloth vs dish towel. In any case dish towel ( to wipe dishes) is by far the most used term in US.

Comment: @BobJarvis: It's a common French expression. Just a minor joke.

Comment: @LarsH I'm in the UK and a dishcloth to me is also the cloth used to wash the dishes.

Comment: Same here "dish cloths" are smaller, usually made of a different material and have a different purpose, namely washing not drying. A drying-up cloth (=tea towel) is for drying only. (RP speaker)

Comment: Dish cloths are small, thin, nearly-square pieces of cloth used for washing dishes or wiping countertops. Dish towels are larger and are used for drying dishes or hands. Dish towel thickness varies. Growing up, we had thick dish towels for washing hands, but thin dish towels for drying dishes.

Answer (score 33):

I am American and familiar with "tea towel", but I think more commonly you'll see them called "[kitchen towels](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/s/kitchen-towels)".   I would be surprised to find them in a gift store - they don't strike me as very collectible items.  That may be the larger cultural disconnect.

Comment: Oh that's confusing to me as a BrEng speaker! Kitchen towel or kitchen roll is the disposable paper stuff. I love how many subtle differences there are between BrEng and AmEng!

Comment: Souvenir shops will have the city/country's name and map plastered over it. I have an aunt who loves collecting tea-towels.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Not to be confused with [cute lace doilies](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doily).  This sort of decorative hand towel is often part of the kitchen’s seasonal décor, and so are often swapped out seasonally by people who care about that sort of thing.

Comment: @JamesWebster- We just call those *paper towels*

Comment: @tchris - Mari-LouA is right.  There are apparently many [souvenier kitchen/dish towels](http://www.amazon.com/California-State-Souvenir-Dish-Towel/dp/B003ZK2XUC).  Never knew that :)

Comment: +1 for "*the larger cultural disconnect*".  In the States we have our own odd collectibles...

Comment: "Bath and Body Works" stocks them as "Kitchen Towels", and while you can get any Holiday theme, you can also get Paris themed, New York, etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Depends where you are, etc. My mother-in-law collects thimbles, and when we were in Vegas last year we looked everywhere - no thimbles to be found until we went out to Hoover Dam.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy thimbles are more difficult to find in souvenir shops, but I did see them in Ireland :) Souvenir *tea-towels* or [*tea cloths*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tea-cloth) in  Europe are cheap, colourful, light-weight, take up no room in your luggage, so pretty much ideal. Funny how the expression *tea cloth* just popped in my head.

Comment: @Jim We (UK) use that term too, but it's different. Paper towels come in single, folded sheets. Kitchen roll comes in a perforated roll, like toilet roll.

Answer (score 19):

As an American, I can tell you that we have many different absorbent materials in our kitchens.  Here's an inventory of ours, along with the typical uses.

- **Dish towel** - always kept clean of food or hand contamination, used only to dry clean dishes after washing them.  Sometimes known as flour-sack towels, they are flat, 100% cotton. They are often printed with a design, or occasionally embroidered for decoration.  These are what you would likely call tea towels.
- **Kitchen towel** - multipurpose towel used for hand drying, counter drying, and absorbing food or drink spills in an emergency.  Generally thicker than a dish towel, often made of a terry cloth. These tend to be more utilitarian, and generally not as decorative as a dish towel.
- **Paper towel** - disposable paper towels used for many of the same purposes, but also for cleaning up non-food messes (dog accidents, mud, heavy grease, etc) where there is no desire to contaminate a food prep towel.
- **Dish rag** - A small towel used for scrubbing dirty dishes.
- **Sponge** - Almost all kitchen sponges are artificial, made of open-cell foam.  Larger ones are used to absorb large quantities of spilled liquids, smaller ones are used to hold a soapy mixture for scrubbing dirty dishes. Some sponges may have a non-abrasive plastic mesh on one side for aggressively scrubbing baked-on foods from pots and pans.
- **Scrubbing pad** - often called by a brand name, such as a Brillo pad or a Scotchbrite pad, these are a stainless steel mesh and are used to aggressively scrub baked-on foods from pots and pans.

Comment: This seems to mirror standard kitchens here quite well, except we use a regular (larger) terrycloth towel for hand-drying, and a separate, small, rectangular, non-terrycloth (but also not cotton) one for counter wiping and spill absorption. And of course our dish rag is a dish brush. I might call a scrubbing pad a scouring pad, but at least there's no confusion as to _what_ those are.

Answer (score 7):

Mirroring John Deters' answer, here is an inventory for the British kitchen (well, Home Counties English - I'm sure there are further local variants):

- **Tea-towel, or drying-up cloth** - [=JD's Dish towel] clean, thin, absorbant, passed from generation to generation until disintegrating. Commemorative pictures, flowery patterns, rude phrases.
- **Hand towel** - towel for drying hands, when in the kitchen. Made of terry cloth, fluffy, plain.
- **Kitchen towel, or paper towel, or kitchen paper** - paper towel, on a roll. Only with patterns if you have some sort of obsession or spend too much time in the supermarket.
- **Dishcloth, or J-cloth** - a cloth, generally damp, used for wiping dishes during washing. And for occasional worktop spills. Required to be blue or green and white gingham pattern by laws of decency.
- **Sponge** - yes. Usually with scouring pad on the top.
- **Scourer** - green, scratchy flat cloth, used to remove stubborn things from metal pans. Capable of destroying the nice china, non-stick surfaces. Sometimes a brillo pad or other metallic pad instead, or as well if enthusiastic.
- **Bridget brush** - plastic-fronded brush with a long handle, for attacking pans, jugs, glasses that are hard to clean with the sponge/scourer; often non-stick friendly. Best ones are pink.
- **Bottle brush** - wire-bound brush with radial fronds and a long handle, for poking inside bottles where nothing else fits. White, and for those over 45 only.

Comment: +1 for J-Cloth, which of course is a brand name, and proper ones have become increadingly difficult to find. But I've never heard a wasshing-up brush called a "Bridget brush". Is that a family-specific thing?

Comment: @MartinMcCallion I'm Irish, but we speak English. I've heard of all of the above bar one. Like yourself I've never heard of a **Bridget Brush**. Google doesn't seem to recognise it either. There is a Bridget L. Brush on LinkedIn though...

Comment: Your "Bridget brush" is (more) commonly known as just a washing-up brush, surely.  And "kitchen towel" may in certain (probably obvious at the time) contexts refer to a hand towel intended for the kitchen.

Comment: A search on google for me shows up lots of instances of Bridget Brush, including Google Shopping entries. Mostly Addis branded, so perhaps it is specific to them, but I'm fairly sure I bought such a thing under a supermarket's own brand.

Comment: There's also the term [*tea cloth*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/tea-cloth) Various items connected to the sink sphere http://dictionary.cambridge.org/topics/kitchen-equipment/washing-the-dishes/

Comment: My 18 year-old daughter has a bottle brush, for cleaning bottles for baby formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hawkeye,

The problem with America is it is so wide spread that we don't always call items by the same name. We have pop, soda, and coke for referring to a carbonated soda depending on where you are from.

I have heard of tea towels all my life but I have heard then called wash clothes, cheese cloths (even if that isn't technically correct), hand towels, and kitchen towels. You might have better luck if you ask them if they carry any kitchen items or items used in the kitchen. It might at least get you in the correct part of the store.

I hope you are having a lovely trip here.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a very regional occurrence to call it a "tea towel" here in the United States.  I have lived in California, Arizona, and Connecticut and have NEVER heard it referred to as a tea towel.  Washcloth, dishcloth, dish towel, hand towel, kitchen towel, and dishrag are the only ones I have used or heard to it referred to as.  If any of the previous posters would kindly put in their state of residence, it would go a long way in figuring out the state by state peculiarities.  I have never personally made a distinction between the one used to dry a  dish versus the one used to clean, as my family has always used sponges for actually cleaning the dishes so the cloth was always for drying.   Now we just use the dishwasher 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the need to chime in here, as I thought there were some interesting responses. Tea towel is most certainly a term used here in the US. They are commonly given as gifts, especially for weddings, and are often hand embroidered with flowers, monograms, etc. A keepsake item. The term has the same usage as British English. However, they may not be as common a souvenir item. If you go into any kitchen store or home decor gift shop, they will most certainly know what you are talking about. On the other hand, a souvenir shop that sells magnets, etc. isn't likely to have them. And if you're at a large retail store (or being attended by a younger person,) it's quite possible they won't know what you're talking about, but most kitchen sections will have some option of linen tea towel, albeit plain.

Comment: Hi TJF. Welcome to the site. We are a bit different from other sites - please look at [The Tour](http://english.stckexchange.com/tour) to find out why. One of the ways we are different is that this space is reserved for answers to the question, whereas your post reads more like a comment. Please make posts here specifically answers to the question that stand on their own. Once again, welcome.